# Advantage SQL INSERT error

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I'm trying to insert a row in a table on an Advantage SQL Server and I keep getting this error:

> Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2124;
>       [Extended Systems][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid operand for operator:

```
INSERT INTO CardExe
  (COD_EXAME,COD_MED,DATA_EXAME,DNT_NUM,ESTADO,HORA_EXAME,NUM_EPS,NUM_MARCA,QTD_EXAME) 
VALUES
  ('C40315','2854',{d '2011-10-17'},'420929F2','R',{t '11:40:00'},'45,0','2006116583',1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type of data field is NUM_EPS?   It appears you are putting 45,0 into it.   MIGHT be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @Sparky, I agree, try and replace `45,0` with `45.0`

Comment: Its not working with '45,0', '45.0', '45', 45... Also not working with our without escaping sequences... How can I find the column datatypes of a view?

Comment: Sparky was, after all, right! We tried to change it to 45.0 but by that time we had tried other stuff and the insert was wrong for different reasons... Thank you all!

Comment: @Sparky - You should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What type of data field is NUM_EPS? It appears you are putting 45,0 into it.

**MIGHT be the cause of the problem**

Comment: Yep... It should be '45.0', not '45,0'